# winforms transparency and terminal services app mode

Tags: c#, winforms, terminal-services

This is a stab in the dark as it seems the code is doing what it should but...

I have a winforms app that I forced a transparent background on. This works great when run locally but this is going to be run in TS app mode and when that happens the transparent parts, rounded corners and just a sliver on each edge, will show the remote machines background. The TS machine is using a solid color bg. Depending on what the users screen looks like it can contrast and show quite a bit.

Is there anyway to get it to not show that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is to make all windows rectangular and nontransparent if running in terminal mode. The SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession property helps to determine this.